How to create a token standard?
I need to create my own token standard for a project because I can't find anything that fits my requirements. When I tried looking this up online, I only saw results for 'how to create your own token', not token standard.

Can I write a smart contract for it just for the project even if it isn't accepted by the community?

I plan to use this token with MetaMask. They state that, "you can use MetaMask on any Ethereum-compatible network, with any Ethereum-compatible token". For the token to be Ethereum-compatible, would it have to be accepted by the community?


Thanks!

To answer you it needs to be broken down into three parts:

1) Standards
On Ethereum a standard, also called EIP (Ethereum Improvement Proposal), is generally set of features and processes that will define a scope and a goal.
ERCs (Ethereum Request for Comments) are application standards EIPs that will generally be defined by set of Solidity functions and functionalities.

To become a standard the proposal has to follow an extensive peer reviewing process before becoming Final and be accepted as a standard by the community.

Idea, Draft, Review, Last Call, Final, Stagnant, Withdrawn and Living.


2) Interfaces
That said what you are talking about may not be creating a standard, that should go through the peer review process, but create your own set of rules.
To do that and have others be able to interact with your contract easily what you can create are Solidity Interfaces. They are special types of Solidity contracts that define only the header of functions.
They are very useful for interaction, interoperability and verification.

3) Interactions
Lastly, Metamask can help you interact with any smart contracts on a supported Network.
However it will NOT offer features such as direct reading of data, function calls ... Those are accessible to only Highly used and supported ERCs. The only 3 that Metamask supports natively right now are ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155.
To interact with your own contract you will have to use your own interfaces, such as creating a Dapp (Decentralized Application) and use the Metamask API.
For testing and easy deployment purposes Remix can be extremely useful for beginners or experts, as it will allow you to interact with your contract without having to create a whole complex interface.

This was really helpful. Thank you.

If my answer helped do not hesitate to upvote it and accept it as the answer to your question !

sorry, I forgot. Also, the upvote wont show because I don't have enough reputation. But I did upvote

Yes, and please accept this as the answer to your question if you think it does.
